# C# - X509Certificate Signature with the Private Key

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I am having a problem using a certificate. I need to extract a certificate (P12) from a store, retrieve its Private Key using a given Password, create a digital signature of the private key using the SHA1 algorithm and, finally, convert the signed signature to base64 format. I am using the following code, but it is a complete mess up:

```
 private string GetCertificado(string strNCertif)
    {
        //Certificado RSA PKCS#12 (.P12) 

        string strPKI = string.Empty;

        X509Store stoLocalizCertif = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        stoLocalizCertif.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection Resultado =
                stoLocalizCertif.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, strNCertif, true);
        if (!(Resultado.Count.Equals(0)))
        {

            X509Certificate2 objCertificado = Resultado[0];

            var objChvPrv = objCertificado.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            byte[] bytCertifValor = Resultado.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "password"); //-> Key not valid for use in specified state.

            byte[] bytAssinatura = objChvPrv.SignData(bytCertifValor, new SHA1Managed());
            byte[] bytCodific = SHA1Managed.Create().ComputeHash(bytCertifValor);
            RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter objFormata = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(objCertificado.PrivateKey);
            objFormata.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
            bytAssinatura = objFormata.CreateSignature(bytCodific);

            strPKI = Convert.ToBase64String(bytAssinatura);

            stoLocalizCertif.Close();
        }
        return strPKI;
    }
```

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I could be reading this wrong, but are you just trying to get the "thumbprint" of a certificate? If so, that data is already included in the results you get from Certificates.Find

Comment: Is the private key exportable if you check in the certifcate manager? Can you include the exact exception string?

Comment: and what is the question? What doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Matti: No, no thumbprint - I can get the right certificate from the store and retrieve the private key but then I just do not know what to do because I need to create a digital signature with that private key using the SHA1 algorithm.

Comment: @Jeff Cyr: Yes it is, I've chekced - However, It wasn't me the creator of the certificate.

Comment: @CryptoGuy: I know the question is difficult because this code is to be used with a constructor from the CA SDM-Service Desk Manager framework (loginServiceManaged(policy, encrypted_policy)). I have a piece of code but is in JAVA and I cannot replicate to C#. You can check it if you're curious: http://java.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/java-l/java-ssl-3053276 (not much code)

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get what is your question. What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: @CryptoGuy: It is very simple: I cannot login because it gives me errors: If I use: byte[] bytCertifValor = Resultado.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "password"); it gives me "Key not valid for use in specified state." If I use byte[] bytCertifValor = Resultado.Export(X509ContentType.Cert, "password"); it gives me "Invalid login policy encryption" - I know I am doing something wrong but I do not know what...